# Define values for second axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I would like to plot a `geom_bar` associate with a `geom_line` on the same graph.
My data look like:

```
head(df)

       Ingenuity Canonical Pathways -log(p-value) Ratio
1         Mitochondrial Dysfunction          5.83 0.105
2         Oxidative Phosphorylation          4.96 0.119
3 Cyclins and Cell Cycle Regulation          3.38 0.111
4           Citrulline Biosynthesis          2.80 0.333
```

Code I use to plot:

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=df[,1], y=df[,2]),stat="identity",fill="blue", colour="black") + 
  geom_line(aes(x=df[,1], y=df[,3]), group=1) + 
  scale_y_continuous("-log(pvalue)",sec.axis = sec_axis(~./5, name="ratio")) +
  coord_flip()
```

Produces:

[image]

I read post here and on other website, and I cannot find the way to link ratio expression (black line) with the second axis graduation. It seems that the black line relates to the first axis!

Sorry if this is a naive question!

Comment: don't use `df[,1]` inside `aes`. Specify the columns by the names! In addition it is recommended to use `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar` for `stat="identity"`

Comment: Thanks for these remarks!